# DotnetNuke email body format

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm using *DotNetNuke 5.06*.

I'm using the event notification system to send a notification email when the admin edits any user details. The email works fine but the email body contains the edited user data without format like this:

```
UserID3FirstNamesameh22LastNameali2UserNameahmedEmailsameh@te5s2.com
```

Is there a way to help me format the email body?

I already tried to search but it seems DDN allows some but not all event notifications to have an edit window in the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Admin - Languages - and edit site resource file you will see all settings. you should be able to find the email format there.

Another thing I noticed is, email format should be html but your email looks like text formatted so content is not readable.

Hope this helps